# Problema con Fragment en android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

Me encuentro desarrollando mi aplicación de una galería de fotos con `fragment`, la cual abre la cámara y va tomando fotos y añadiéndolas al `fragment` mediante un objeto fotografía.

Pues resulta que al añadir solo 1 foto, sin problemas, pero a la hora de añadir una segunda foto se me cierra la `app` y me sale el siguiente error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.proyectofinalmio, PID: 5023
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@8cbd0f2
        at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(BaseCanvas.java:62)
        at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:226)
        at android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(RecordingCanvas.java:98)
        at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:545)
        at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1360)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20207)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19082)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.widget.ListView.drawChild(ListView.java:3590)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:2639)
        at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3585)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20210)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:4320)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19082)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20210)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:780)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19082)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:686)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:692)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:801)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3311)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3115)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2484)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7183)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Por aquí les dejo las `clases`:

`MainActivity`:

```
package com.example.proyectofinalmio.Control;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.proyectofinalmio.Modelo.Fotografia;
import com.example.proyectofinalmio.R;

import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MainFragment.onFotoSeleccionada, NuevaFotoFragment.onBotonFotoPulsado,
                                                                MainFragment.OnFABPulsadoListener, NuevaFotoFragment.OnInsertarPulsado,
                                                                FragmentFotoGrande.onBotonFotoPulsadoBorrar{
    private static final int MY_PERMISION_REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;



    //Fragmen
    MainFragment mainFragment=null;
    NadaSeleccionado nadaSeleccionado= null;
    FragmentFotoGrande fragmentFotoGrande = null;
    NuevaFotoFragment nuevaFotoFragment = null;

    //Cargamos los layout de los fragments

    FrameLayout layoutMain;
    FrameLayout layoutLarger;

    Fotografia fotografia = null;
    ImageView imageView;
    ImageView fotoAA;
    Bitmap bitmap;



    //CODIGO PARA INTENT DE CÁMARA
    public static final int CAMARA=0;

    private int posicion;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //RECUPERO LOS LAYOUT DE LOS FRAME

        layoutMain = findViewById(R.id.frameLayoutMain);
        layoutLarger= findViewById(R.id.frameLayoutLarge);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        //muestro los fragments
        mainFragment = new MainFragment();

        transaction.add(R.id.frameLayoutMain,mainFragment);

        if (grande()){
            nadaSeleccionado = new NadaSeleccionado();
            transaction.add(R.id.frameLayoutLarge,nadaSeleccionado);

        }

        transaction.commit();
        //Permisos camara
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        MY_PERMISION_REQUEST_CAMERA);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean grande(){

        return (layoutLarger !=null);
    }



    //lanza el fragment de la foto
    @Override
    public void onFotoSeleccionada(int posicion) {

        this.posicion= posicion;

        Fotografia fotografia = mainFragment.arrayAdapter.getItem(posicion);

        if (grande()){ //TABLETS

            fragmentFotoGrande = new FragmentFotoGrande();

            fragmentFotoGrande = FragmentFotoGrande.newInstance(fotografia);

            FragmentTransaction transaction= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayoutLarge,fragmentFotoGrande);
            transaction.commit();

        }else{

            //moviles
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBotonFotoPulsado() {
        Intent i= new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(i, CAMARA);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch(requestCode) {

            case CAMARA:
                bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
                imageView = findViewById(R.id.nuevaFoto);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFABPulsado() {

        if (grande()){

            nuevaFotoFragment = NuevaFotoFragment.newInstance(null);
            FragmentTransaction transaction=
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayoutLarge,nuevaFotoFragment);
            transaction.commit();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInsertarPulsado(Fotografia fotografia) {

        EditText descripcion = findViewById(R.id.et_descripcion);
        NuevaFotoFragment.fotografia.setNombre(descripcion.getText().toString());

        EditText pais = findViewById(R.id.et_pais);
        NuevaFotoFragment.fotografia.setPais(pais.getText().toString());

        EditText resumen = findViewById(R.id.et_resumen);
        NuevaFotoFragment.fotografia.setComentario(resumen.getText().toString());

        ImageView foto = findViewById(R.id.nuevaFoto);
        foto.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bitmap = foto.getDrawingCache();
        NuevaFotoFragment.fotografia.setFoto(bitmap);


        if (posicion== -1){

            mainFragment.arrayAdapter.add(nuevaFotoFragment.fotografia);

        }else{

            mainFragment.arrayAdapter.remove(fotografia);
            mainFragment.arrayAdapter.insert(fotografia,posicion);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBotonFotoPulsadoBorrar() {

        fotografia = mainFragment.arrayAdapter.getItem(posicion);
        mainFragment.arrayAdapter.remove(fotografia);
        posicion= -1;

        FragmentTransaction transaction= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayoutLarge,nadaSeleccionado);
        transaction.commit();


    }
}
```

`NuevaFotoFragment` el cual es el `Fragment` que me crea la nueva foto

```
package com.example.proyectofinalmio.Control;


import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.proyectofinalmio.Modelo.Fotografia;
import com.example.proyectofinalmio.R;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class NuevaFotoFragment extends Fragment {


    //INTERFAZ PARA ABRIR LA CAMARA

    //VAMOS A CREAR LA INTERFAZ PARA ABRIR LA CAMARA

    public interface onBotonFotoPulsado{

        public void onBotonFotoPulsado();
    }

    //Guardar nueva imagen

    public interface OnInsertarPulsado{
        public void onInsertarPulsado(Fotografia fotografia);
    }

    onBotonFotoPulsado abrirCamara;
    OnInsertarPulsado listener_pulsado=null;


    public static Fotografia fotografia;

    public NuevaFotoFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    //METODO ESTATICO PARA CREAR NUEVA FOTO

    public static NuevaFotoFragment newInstance(Fotografia fotografia){

        NuevaFotoFragment fragment = new NuevaFotoFragment();

        if (fotografia == null){
            NuevaFotoFragment.fotografia = new Fotografia("","","","");

        }

        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View result = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nueva_foto, container, false);


        //Darle vida al boton para que habra la camara

        Button boton = result.findViewById(R.id.abrirCamara);

        boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Para abrir la camara
                abrirCamara.onBotonFotoPulsado();
                //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"HOLA",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        Button bInsertar = result.findViewById(R.id.guardarFoto);

        bInsertar.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //componer el libro y pasarlo a la activity
                        fotografia.setComentario("");
                        listener_pulsado.onInsertarPulsado(fotografia);
                    }
                }
        );


        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        abrirCamara = (onBotonFotoPulsado) context;
        listener_pulsado = (OnInsertarPulsado) context;

    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        abrirCamara = null;
        listener_pulsado= null;
    }

}
```

Se me olvidaba comentar que el error sucede al hacer la 2 foto y darle al tick que tiene la camara de android

Gracias de antemano a todos

Answer (score 2):

En este caso como menciona el error estas tratando de usar un Bitmap reciclado, te sugiero que antes de agregar otro bitmap a tu ImageView, elimines el que se encuentra.

Esto podrías realizarlo al realizar el intent para abrir la camara:

```
   @Override
    public void onBotonFotoPulsado() {
        Intent i= new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(i, CAMARA);

        //Elimina imagen de ImageView
        imageView.setImageBitmap(null);

    }
```

---

Obtén la referencia de tu `ImageView` en `onCreate()`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   imageView = findViewById(R.id.nuevaFoto);

   ...
   ...
```

no es necesario realizarlo dentro de `onActivityResult()`

Comment: Buenas tardes Elenasys, tu solucion me sigue dando el mismo fallo, ya que si lo pongo como tu me da null y se lo meto en un if me da el mismo error

Comment: @SergioAlcalde en que clase y linea te muestra este error?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.proyectofinalmio.Control.MainActivity.onBotonFotoPulsado(MainActivity.java:136)
        at com.example.proyectofinalmio.Control.NuevaFotoFragment$1.onClick(NuevaFotoFragment.java:79)

Comment: @SergioAlcalde es un error diferente, ve la edición de mi respuesta y realiza este cambio también y prueba nuevamente.

Comment: me da el siguiente error al hacer esos cambios  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.proyectofinalmio.Control.MainActivity.onBotonFotoPulsado(MainActivity.java:138)
        at com.example.proyectofinalmio.Control.NuevaFotoFragment$1.onClick(NuevaFotoFragment.java:79)